# HTML5 Geolocation Trouble

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a Java script for HTML 5 geolocation but it doesnt seem to work and when I try to output the contents in another scope, it says undefined. Below is the code.

```
<script>
var lat;
var lng;
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
     lat = position.coords.latitude;
     lng = position.coords.longitude;
     document.write(lat); // Doesnt output anything
  }


</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
          document.write(lat);      // It says undefined
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
             //some scripts here

         }

</script>
```

Comment: this isnt script error, there is something else, like local test, or youre not giving permission to the browser

Answer (score 0):

The success callback functions are called only when the html page is hosted on a web server, not in localhost. Are you testing locally or on a webserver?

Comment: Apparantly Chrome only allows you to track your location from trused/securized servers wich have SSL, HTTPS or other encryption methods. Check the [Google Product forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/vhDaFt-pOfA/t1euklGluFkJ)

Comment: @Nielslnc, the issue was not on hosting  or scoping but on the asynchronous nature of java script. The reason why document.write() was null is because the document.write() was executing before the geolocation. I managed to get the program working by executing the function right inside the showPosition(position) function

Comment: Allright! Good for you that you fixed it! It just had the same symptoms of the error that I get when attempting to test in localhost so I figured I would share that with you.